# Use regular expression to extract specific string

Tags: r, regex

I have a data fame contain string and POS tags. I want to extract specific string by filtering on specific POS tags.

For a simple example, I want to extract strings which is  "NN-NN-NN" and "VB-JJ-NN" base.

```
df <- data.frame(word = c("abrasion process management", 
                          "slurries comprise abrasive", 
                          "slurry compositions comprise ", 
                          "keep high polishing", 
                          "improved superabrasive grit", 
                          "using ceriacoated silica",
                          "and grinding",
                          "for cmp",
                          "and grinding for"),
                 pos_tag = c("NN-NN-NN", "NNS-NN-NN", "NN-NNS-NN", "VB-JJ-NN", 
                             "VBN-JJ-NN", "VBG-JJ-NN", "CC-VBG", "IN-NN", "CC-VBG-IN"))

> df
               word              pos_tag
1   abrasion process management  NN-NN-NN
2    slurries comprise abrasive  NNS-NN-NN
3 slurry compositions comprise   NN-NNS-NN
4           keep high polishing  VB-JJ-NN
5   improved superabrasive grit  VBN-JJ-NN
6      using ceriacoated silica  VBG-JJ-NN
7                  and grinding  CC-VBG
8                       for cmp  IN-NN
9              and grinding for  CC-VBG-IN
```

I tried use regular expression to define my pattern.
But I think it's not a efficient way to define pattern.
Are there other more efficient ways?

```
pos <- c("NN-NN-NN", "NNS-NN-NN", "NN-NNS-NN", "VB.-JJ-NN", "VB-JJ-NN")
pos2 <- paste0('^', pos , "\\w*$", collapse = '|')
sort_string <- df[grep(pos2,  df$pos_tag),] %>%
               unique()
```

here is what I want to get

```
               word              pos_tag
1   abrasion process management  NN-NN-NN
2    slurries comprise abrasive  NNS-NN-NN
3 slurry compositions comprise   NN-NNS-NN
4           keep high polishing  VB-JJ-NN
5   improved superabrasive grit  VBN-JJ-NN
6      using ceriacoated silica  VBG-JJ-NN
```

Comment: In the expected u have `NNS-NN-NN`  The pattern is not clear

Comment: the question is not very clear. Let me see if I understood: you want to take the "i" element from word and to match it to the "i" element from the pos_tag, writting out to a file/console the lines from 1 to "i", where "i" stands for the looping index control. You also want to print the line number. It is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions for that. A possibility is to use the `amatch`-function from the `stringdist`-package:

```
vec <- c("NN-NN-NN", "VB-JJ-NN")

library(stringdist)
df[!!amatch(df$pos_tag, vec, maxDist = 1, nomatch = 0),]
```

which gives:

```
                           word   pos_tag
1   abrasion process management  NN-NN-NN
2    slurries comprise abrasive NNS-NN-NN
3 slurry compositions comprise  NN-NNS-NN
4           keep high polishing  VB-JJ-NN
5   improved superabrasive grit VBN-JJ-NN
6      using ceriacoated silica VBG-JJ-NN
```

What this does:

- `amatch(df$pos_tag, vec, maxDist = 1, nomatch = 0)` looks whether values in `df$pos_tag` match the values in `vec` with a specified tolerance in difference.
- In this case I used a maximum allowed editdistance of 1 character: `maxDist = 1`
- By a double negation, `!!` you create a logical vector that indicates whether `pos_tag` (almost) matches with one of the values in vec. An alternative is: `df[amatch(df$pos_tag, vec, maxDist = 1, nomatch = 0) > 0,]`

---

You could also do this in base R with `agrep`/`agrepl` in combination with `sapply`/`lapply` and `rowSums`/`unlist`:

```
# method 1:
df[rowSums(sapply(vec, function(x) agrepl(x, df$pos_tag, max.distance = 1))) > 0,]

# method 2:
df[unlist(lapply(vec, function(x) agrep(x, df$pos_tag, max.distance = 1))),]
```

both will give you the same result.

Comment: wow~ It's really a efficient way. I have use this way in my process. But it shows another problem. Because in my data fame also have such as "IN-NN-NN", "VB-RB-IN","NN-IN-NN" pos tags. (Sorry I didn't shows all pos tag in my example df). So when I use amatch() It also  extract other patterns which I don't want.

Comment: @Eva it depends on how much 'false'  matches you do have, but a possibility is to filter out the false matches with `!df$pos_tag %in% c("IN-NN-NN", "VB-RB-IN","NN-IN-NN")`